# JavaFX 13 create runnable jar "no main manifest attribute"

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I am trying to make my jar run. It builds and all but when I try to run the jar it says:

`no main manifest attribute, in Sagrada.jar`

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.12.0'
}

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.18'
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = "$moduleName/nl.avans.sagrada.MainApp"

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'Sagrada'
    }
}
```

Then I run Tasks > application > run which works fine. But when I try to build a jar with Tasks > build > build or Tasks > build > jar it outputs this jar with the problem described above.

I followed JavaFX 13 tutorial: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/
Then `JavaFX and IntelliJ > Modular with Gradle`

I don't want the image but a runnable jar which I need for a school project.

I did check the `Path` variables which are set to the right Java. I also tried to run the jar with `jar -jar Sagrada.jar nl.avans.sagrada.MainApp`.

Answer (score 2):

You did not define a "manifest - attribute" in your gradle build.

You should specify the "jar" task like that :

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'your.main.package.MainApp'
    )

  }
  from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

You should also Clarify the nessecary moduls.

You can do this via the `module-info.java` or use the "compileJava" task in gradle, to declare the VM arguments for compilation.

**gradle**:

```
compileJava {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics'
        ]
        println options.compilerArgs
    }

}
```

**module-info.java**

```
module ProjectName {

requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires transitive javafx.graphics;

// specify the package the uses the modules
opens com.your.package to javafx.fxml, javafx.controls;

exports org.openjfx;

}
```

i Hope that helps

Also you should use a Launcher, that Starts the Application and not use the Application as main class (in the case you did not already did this).
Your Main Class should not Extend Application.

```java
public class AppLauncher{

     public static void main(String args[]){
           Application.launch(YourApplication.class,args)

     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not I get this error: `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`